# Background image position dompdf css2

Tags: css, dompdf

I have a `td` and I need it to have a specific bottom border when exported as PDF. I have tried many css snippets, however, nothing really solved the issue. This is the closiest that I got and works perfectly in a browser:

```
td.underline-dotted-thin{
    background-image: url('../thin-dots.png');
    background-position: bottom left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

However when the screen is exported as PDF with `dompdf`, the last two properties (`background-position` and `background-repeat`) are not applied.

Any help or guidance for how to solve this issue is much appreciated.

**EDIT**

The image is visible in the exported pdf, however, it is in the middle of `td` and is stretched.

Comment: Is the `background-image` itself seen in the exported PDF?

Comment: Yes it is seen, but in the middle of the `td` and it seems stretched.

Comment: Have you tried setting a `background-size` on the element?

Comment: Just tried that, But the image is still vertically in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of the most recent release (v0.7.0) dompdf does not support `background-position` or `background-size`.